# FLEX: how to assign different z-index?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a canvas with a mxml component and I'm dynamically adding components to the canvas.

These components are overlying the mxml component. How can I keep the mxml component on top ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved with

```
canvas.setChildIndex(dragPanel,canvas.getChildren().length-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lay down a container component (VBox/HBox or similar), then your component. Then add the new items to the container that lies under the MXML component, as follows:

```
Canvas
|
----------------VBox
|               |
|               |
----MXMLComp    ----Dynamic added component
                |
                |
                ----Dynamic added component
```

Comment: I've a canvas and I added my component to it (in MXML). Then I dynamically add LinkButtons to the canvas (on which my component lies). So, I guess, I'm doing what you suggest.

Comment: No, you're not. You're adding all items to a single container. I'll update my answer.